# Galaxy S3 heats up while using net or data

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, overheating

My phone gets very hot while using internet or data and it starts going slow. Can you tell me if something is physically wrong or give any advice on how to rectify the problem.

Comment: I see lots of threads and suggestions on websites here https://www.google.co.in/search?q=galaxy+s3+overheating+issue+using+internet&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=QJVBVSvUnroEv8yBgAQ Did you try any of them before posting your question? What were your results with them? Please mention the details as much as possible about the troubleshooting you did. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There have been several reports of the S3 experiencing heat problems.

> Many users have reported problems with their Galaxy S3 overheating and
>   sometimes even freezing or crashing as a result. The S3 is very thin
>   with a big screen, a big battery, and a powerful set of internal
>   components, so the more you use it, the hotter it will get. This
>   generally only rears its head as an issue after prolonged gaming or if
>   you do something else that’s graphically intensive. If your Galaxy S3
>   is getting very hot and crashing without intensive use, then you might
>   have a hardware problem.
>
> Solution: The obvious solution is to take a break for a few minutes
>   and let the phone cool down. If you’ve been running something for
>   hours, then it will inevitably heat up. If it is heating up on standby
>   or with low levels of usage, then you should contact the seller or
>   carrier and check if the hardware is faulty. You should be able to get
>   a replacement handset if they confirm the problem.

Read more: http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/galaxy-s3-problems-what-users-complain-about-the-most/#ixzz3XabgupCo 
Follow us: @digitaltrends on Twitter | digitaltrendsftw on Facebook

If you use a case for your phone, make sure the case is appropriate for the phone so that any heat can dissipate.  You may also want to try an app like [Clean Master](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard&hl=en) that can warn you if the phone is experiencing a heat problem.  Beyond that, you may have a rogue app that could be responsible.

Comment: "The obvious solution is to take a break for a few minutes and let the phone cool down." -- Repeated cooling and heating can damage the internals of a PC. Is it dangerous for phones and tablets too? (and I'm genuinly asking, the insides could be waaay different for all I know)